# Higher ramification groups

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I was wondering if someone could explain what higher ramification groups are used for? What information do they contain and why are they important?

Answer (score 6):

Some more-or-less random things that come to mind:

- There is the formula for computing the [different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Different_ideal) of a field extension in terms of the sizes of the higher ramification groups.

  The higher ramification groups correspond to naturally arising groups of local units; namely, their image under the Artin map are precisely the higher powers of the local 1-units.

  In fact, historically more basic than the previous point is that the first very careful proofs of Kronecker-Weber (i.e., before class field theory existed) by Hilbert heavily involved the use of the higher ramification groups.

  They turn out to provide the correct fix to Euler factors of L-functions at "bad" places (where "bad" depends on your context.)  This would require a rather long digression, so let me just mention the [Hasse-Arf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse-Arf_theorem) and the [Artin conductor.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin_conductor)

Answer (score 3):

- In basic Galois theory, to add to Cam's answers: they provide information on whether an extension is tame or wildly ramified and thus give a more complete picture
- Sheaf theoretically: for example, higher ramification groups give an important invariant called the Swan conductor which is used in the Ogg-Shafarevich formula for computing Euler characteristics of curves. This formula has been generalized by Deligne, Laumon, and more recently Kato-Saito for higher dimensions.